# Adding multiple UIButton to multiple UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiview, uibutton

I have written code below that programmatically creates multiple `UIButton` that are placed on different `UIView`. All buttons are similar and different by button title. The code does accomplish what it needs to do, but as you can see, the code is rather verbose, it's too lengthy.

---

**Question**

How can I structure the code below and make it compact and succinct?

---

**Code**

```
let myButton0 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
myButton0.setTitle("Text 0", forState:.Normal)
myButton0.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
myButton0.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
myButton0.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGrayColor()
myButton0.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
myButton0.alpha = 1
myButton0.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
myButton0.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
myButton0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goDoThis0), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myView0.addSubview(myButton0)

let myButton1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
myButton1.setTitle("Text 1", forState:.Normal)
myButton1.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
myButton1.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
myButton1.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGrayColor()
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
myButton1.alpha = 1
myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
myButton1.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
myButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goDoThis1), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myView1.addSubview(myButton1)

let myButton2 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
myButton2.setTitle("Text 2", forState:.Normal)
myButton2.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
myButton2.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
myButton2.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGrayColor()
myButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
myButton2.alpha = 1
myButton2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
myButton2.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
myButton2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goDoThis2), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myView2.addSubview(myButton2)

let myButton3 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
myButton3.setTitle("Text 3", forState:.Normal)
myButton3.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
myButton3.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
myButton3.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGrayColor()
myButton3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
myButton3.alpha = 1
myButton3.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
myButton3.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
myButton3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goDoThis3), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myView3.addSubview(myButton3)

let myButton4 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
myButton4.setTitle("Text 4", forState:.Normal)
myButton4.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
myButton4.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
myButton4.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGrayColor()
myButton4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
myButton4.alpha = 1
myButton4.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
myButton4.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
myButton4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goDoThis4), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myView4.addSubview(myButton4)
```

Comment: This question probably best fits in the core review forum - https://codereview.stackexchange.com - but off the top of my head, why not extend `UIButton`, creating a `convenience` initializer that wraps each button's code into a single call? You can even pass the `addTarget` parameters into the initializer. (I do this all the time.)

Comment: Subclass the uibutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Swift 4.0)
**First**, write a common method for creating button:

```
func createButton(title:String,toView:UIView,action:Selector) {
    let myButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    myButton.setTitle(title, for:.normal)
    myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    myButton.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGray
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
    myButton.alpha = 1
    myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
    myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    toView.addSubview(myButton)
}
```

**Then** create buttons like this:

```
let buttonInfos = [
                      ["Text 0",myView0,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis0)],
                      ["Text 1",myView1,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis1)],
                      ["Text 2",myView2,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis2)],
                      ["Text 3",myView3,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis3)],
                      ["Text 4",myView4,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis4)],
                  ]

for buttonInfo in buttonInfos {
    self.createButton(title: buttonInfo[0] as! String, toView: buttonInfo[1] as! UIView, action: buttonInfo[2] as! Selector)
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The explanation and code showed me a new technique. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

While this question has already been answered, I would like to contribute another approach adapted from [Yun CHEN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46863153/6483149).

Similarly, create a common method for your buttons:

```
func createButton(title:String,toView:UIView,action:Selector) {
    let myButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    myButton.setTitle(title, for:.normal)
    myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    myButton.backgroundColor =  UIColor.darkGray
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
    myButton.alpha = 1
    myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false
    myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    toView.addSubview(myButton)
}
```

Then list out the button information in an array of tuples:

```
let buttonInfos = [
                      ("Text 0",myView0,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis0)),
                      ("Text 1",myView1,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis1)),
                      ("Text 2",myView2,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis2)),
                      ("Text 3",myView3,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis3)),
                      ("Text 4",myView4,#selector(ViewController.goDoThis4)),
                  ]
```

And finally create the buttons like so:

```
for buttonInfo in buttonInfos {
    self.createButton(title: buttonInfo.0, toView: buttonInfo.1, action: buttonInfo.2)
}
```

As you can see in your case, by using tuples, you do not need to cast the types with `as! String` , `as! UIView` etc, simplifying and making the code shorter and safer.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative!